# Google Sheets: Geting the highest score and corresponding name from a sheet/table, when the name is not in a specific list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets. One (called TCTK) contains a formular and when a checkbox is clicked, the data is inserted in another sheet ("Ronin-Games") and then the formular ist emptied.
Now I need a function that search the saved data for some info.

The data in "Ronin-Games" contains something like:

```
Dojo / Winner / Points
#2 / Alpha / 8.6
#1 / Beta / 7.5
#2 / Gamma / 8.3
#3 / Delta / 9.1
#2 / Alpha / 7.1
```

[..]

(appendix ***: the code to enter the data)

I need to get the winner with the most points (if two are tied, it should be the first to reach the points). And it should be determend for every dojo seperate. The third point is, that there is list elsewhere with names, who are not to be considered, because they are promoted because of other reasons (some dojos share a list, other dojos have different lists; right now #1+#2 have the same, #3 have another).

I would like to add a function (named getBest), which does this, called with two parameters. It should be called from the sheet.
The call will be from the sheet with the formular, in which also the list of names is (in the case of #2 in the cells J2:J9).

There will be quite a few dojos (for now there are three, but maybe it will be expanded to 10 or 20 or even 30 - not clear right now). So it should be a function as quick as possible.

I`m new to apps script (2 weeks), my overview of possible function is limited. I would know how to do it in mysql (appendix *), but which functions are the best (fastest) to do it in google sheets? I made some progress with filter (appendix **), but it seems to be slow, even so I only have called it within the script not from the sheet and only one thing is checked so far (the easy thing: search for "#2").

It would be nice to have a hint (it is not needed to have a complete code). I have trouble to find a good function for this. Or maybe my approach is wrong?
Another maybe: Could it also be done to search the data purely within the sheet, without the need for an apps-script-function?

Any idea on this?

On expecting:
Getting the name and the score of the best player from a given Dojo (who is not in a list).

- if it were a db-table with an additional id column (because of two players having the same highscore, the first wins), that would be my mysql:
  `SELECT * from Ronin-Games d WHERE d.dojo = '#2' and d.name not in (select w.name from winnerList1) ORDER by d.points DESC, d.id ASC`

On try:
** first try so far, but seem to be slow, and I´m not sure how to do it with the list of ignored names.

INFO: it is not possible to show the code with the filter-try. I always get the message:
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.
Even so I used the same method like I used at ***, I don´t really understand why.
So I added it as a comment.

*** for complettness, the code to enter the data (a checkbox must be clicked)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rangeModified = e.range;
  var targetWS = e.source.getSheetByName("Ronin-Games");
  var row = rangeModified.getRow();
  var col = rangeModified.getColumn();
  //get info about the roninDojo
  var roninDojoNumber = bereichsTest(row, col, rangeModified); //is false if the wrong cell is edited (clicked)
  if (roninDojoNumber) {
    //first: uncheck the checkbox
    rangeModified.setValue(false);
    //second: get data
    var player_1 = rangeModified.offset(-1,- 2).getValue();
    var player_1_points = parseFloat(rangeModified.offset(-1, -1).getDisplayValue());
    var player_2 = rangeModified.offset(0, -2).getValue();
    var player_2_points = parseFloat(rangeModified.offset(0, -1).getDisplayValue());
    //third: is the data plausibel?
    var err = checkNumbers(player_1_points, player_2_points);
    if(!(player_1) || !(player_2)) {
      err = 'missing playername';
    }
    //if something is wrong a message will be displayed and nothing more is happening
    if(err) {
      Browser.msgBox(err);
      return;
    }
    if(player_1_points > player_2_points) {
      //winner is p1
      targetWS.appendRow([roninDojoNumber, player_1, player_1_points, player_2, player_2_points]);
    } else if (player_1_points < player_2_points) {
      //winner is p2
      targetWS.appendRow([roninDojoNumber, player_2, player_2_points, player_1, player_1_points]);
    } else {
      //placeholder: remis (not possible) MAYBE in another typ of game //rules for remis must be decided first
    }
    //last: delete saved data
    // TO BE DONE //in the test-phase the data may be needed again, should be done easily (setvalue?)

  }
}

function bereichsTest(infoRow, infoCol, rangeModified) {
  if(infoRow > 2 && infoCol > 2) { //legaler Bereich nur ab C3 
    //die Info holen, ob das der richtige Platz ist; Zelleninhalt (zwei hoch und eins nach links) muss vom typ #n sein 
    let infoValue = rangeModified.offset(-2,-1).getValue();
    if(infoValue[0] ==='#') {
      return infoValue;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}

function checkNumbers(one, two) {
  if(isNaN(one)) {
    var err = '1st is not a number';
    return err;
  } 
  if(isNaN(two)){
    var err = '2nd is not a number';
    return err;
  } 
  if(one == two) {
    var err = 'no remis please';
    return err;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Since it didn´t work in the original post, I add appendix ** as a comment:

````function getBest(id, winnerList) {
  //id is something like #2
  //winnerList is an list of already promoted players
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Ronin-Games");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A:C");
  var filter = range.createFilter();
  var crit =  SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo("#2");
  var addFilter = filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, crit);
  filter.remove();
  return true;
}````

Comment: We are not a code writing service.  If you have specific questions about  the code feel free to ask them one at a time, otherwise plan to develop most of the code on your own.

Comment: - [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: As posted, I don´t expect code, I would like to have a hint which function would be best/fastest for this purpose. Or if another approch should be considered.
The info/code in the appendix is only posted the make clear what is the basis of the question.

Comment: One hint would be not to use functions like getRow() and getColumn() for data that already exists in the event object. Also avoid the use of appendRow  and use setValues() instead and try to perform all calculations in an array and use one getValues and one setValues if possible.  You should consider not using the simple trigger.  Use an installible onEdit but change the name of the function otherwise you will be getting two triggers instead of one.  The simple trigger must finish in 30 seconds. Personally, I would not use onEdit at all for this.

Comment: You could develop a side bar timer and let it generate timebased triggers to update the the scoring on a regular basis.  The problem with this question is that there is not one answer.  It is  a design problem and not a script problem so it has as many answers as their are minds to attack it.  So it's just out of the scope of this forum.

Answer (score 0):

(this is a little to long for a comment, even so it cotains response to comments before)

You said appendrow may be no good choice and you are right. I changed the way the data is stored, that makes it a lot easier to use the data. Every dojo get it´s own columns (7+1), so that makes two of the three problems solved. And an arrayformular in the sheet solves the rest.

So the data-saving is still a script, but finding the infos is solved with max, indirect and xlookup within the sheet.

The sheet is used by many people. Two play against each other and the winner enters the result. So many different people will have access and not all of them may be willing to grant permission. What is nessasary if installible  triggers would be used (if I understood it right, what I read in the section about it). So I will stick to onEdit, but with a little change. Some other little things are changed too.

The part with the getRow() and getColumn() is not clear to me. What would be the alternative?

Conclusion:
I found a solution, and your input was very useful.

If (anyone who reads this is) interested in details:
The getBest is off the table and the two underfunctions stayed the same. The actual version of the codes does what it should do. It can be polished of course.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  insertdata(e);
}

function insertdata(e) {  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  //get info about the roninDojo
  var roninDojoId = bereichsTest(row, col, e.range); //is false if the wrong cell is edited (clicked)
  if (roninDojoId) {
    //first: uncheck the checkbox
    e.range.setValue(false);
    //second: get data from the formular
    //The data to be saved must be nullt in the end, so a new range is defined
    var newRange = e.range.getSheet().getRange(row-1,col-2, 2, 2);
    var boxData = newRange.getDisplayValues();
    var player_1 = boxData[0][0];
    var player_1_points = parseFloat(boxData[0][1].replace(',','.'));
    var player_2 = boxData[1][0];
    var player_2_points = parseFloat(boxData[1][1].replace(',','.'));
    //third: is the data plausibel?
    var err = checkNumbers(player_1_points, player_2_points);
    if(!(player_1) || !(player_2)) {
      err = 'missing playername';
    }
    //if something is wrong, a message will be displayed and nothing more is happening
    if(err) {
      Browser.msgBox(err);
      return;
    }
    //fourth: Data is collected for inserting
    var targetWS = e.source.getSheetByName("Ronin-Games");
    var roninDojoNumber = roninDojoId.substring(1,roninDojoId.length);
    //ein 8er block entsteht; Die Spalten 1,6 und 7 (A,F,G) bilden den "Rahmen", 8 bleibt wegen der optik leer; in der ersten Spalte stehen feste Werte, von denen einer nun benötigt wird (count); Sp. 6+7 werden durch arrayformular automatisch berechnet ; 8 bleibt wegen der optik leer; pro dojo gibt es also einen achter-Block, man muss sehen ob 1,9,17,25, ...
    var r1c1_col = (roninDojoNumber-1)*8;
    var r1c1_ref = "R8C"+(r1c1_col+1);
    var someData = targetWS.getRange(r1c1_ref);
    var count = someData.getValue(); //the row-number in which to enter the data
    if(player_1_points > player_2_points) {
      //winner is p1
      var insertArray = [[player_1, player_1_points, player_2, player_2_points]];
    } else if (player_1_points < player_2_points) {
      //winner is p2
      var insertArray = [[player_2, player_2_points, player_1, player_1_points]];
    } else {
      //remis (not possible) MAYBE in another typ of game
    }
    var insertRange = targetWS.getRange("R"+count+"C"+(r1c1_col+2)+":R"+count+"C"+(r1c1_col+5));
    insertRange.setValues(insertArray);
    someData.setValue(count+1);
    //last: delete saved data
    newRange.clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: e.range.columnStart and e.range.rowStart